# Problem about marginal pmfs: I can't understand why it is.

Tags: statistics

(It's the problem of the book 'Introduction to mathematical statistics'. 2.3.9) Five cards are drawn at random and without replacement from an ordinary deck of cards. Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ denote, respectively, the number of spades and the number of hearts that appear in the five cards. (b) Find the two marginal pmfs. I found the joint pmf of $X_1$ and $X_2$, which is $$ P(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2) = \frac{\binom{13}{x_1} \cdot \binom{13}{x_2} \cdot \binom{26}{5 - x_1 - x_2}}{\binom{52}{5}} $$ So I tried to get marginal pmf of $X_1$ by solving summation $P(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2)$ with respect to $x_2$. But I found it's insane.. and then I looked for solution, and its $$ P(X_1 = x_1) = \frac{\binom{13}{x_1} \cdot \binom{39}{x_1}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$ Could you please explain about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean the marginal pmf is
$$ P(X_1 = x_1) = \frac{\binom{13}{x_1} \cdot \binom{39}{5 - x_1}}{\binom{52}{5}}$$
Rather than summing out the $x_2$ (which will work, but is harder) it's easier to derive this from first principles. Each combination of 5 cards is equally likely to be drawn, and there are $\binom{52}{5}$ combinations. We want to find the number of combinations which contains $x_1$ spades. There is $\binom{13}{x_1}$ ways to choose the spades, then $\binom{39}{5 -x _1}$ ways to choose the remaining cards. From this we can derive the formula.

Comment: But why is it possible to exclude x2? Is the marginal pmf of x1 same as x2=0 in the joint pmf?

Comment: No, setting $x_2 = 0$ in the joint pmf would give $\binom{26}{5 - x_1}$ instead of $\binom{39}{5 - x_1}$. It's possible to exclude $x_2$ because that's exactly what the marginal pmf is, the probability of getting $X_1 = x_1$ if we don't care what the value of $X_2$ is